# How is calculated the average current?

Tags: circuit-analysis, power-electronics

I was given a problem, the conditions are:
The voltage and current for a device (using the passive sign convention) are
    periodic functions with    \$T=100 ms\$ described by

\$v(t)=\begin{cases}
10\,V & 0\,ms<t<70\,ms\\
0 & 70\,ms<t<100\,ms
\end{cases}\$

\$i(t)=\begin{cases}
0\,A & 0\,ms<t<50\,ms\\
4\,A & 50\,ms<t<100\,ms
\end{cases}\$

So the questions from the book are instantaneous power, the average power, and  the energy per period, but I have no interest in these, What I really want to know is if 
a DC source is connected to the circuit , how can be calculated the average power? a.k.a. What would be the average current (\$I_{avg}\$)?

I understand that the \$I_{avg}\$ would be the given current over the period

### \$I_{avg}=\frac{4 A}{100 ms}=0.00004 A\$

Comment: Average would be the integral over time period divided by that time period.

Comment: This same question was asked previously in the past 48 hours. What did you learn from the comments you got when you asked before?

Comment: I'm not sure how far off you are, but I will give you a hint, the answer starts with the number 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**
Thanks to Eugene Sh

$$I_{AVG}=\frac{1}{T}\int i(t)dt=\frac{1}{100\times10^{-3}}(\int_{0}^{50\times-3}0+\int_{50\times-3}^{100\times-3}4)dt=2\,A$$